# batch rename multiple mp3's stripping leading digits

Tags: linux, bash, unix, batch-rename

Hi could anyone help me? Im trying to strip leading digits from multiple mp3 files so
"01 some_file.mp3" would become "some_file.mp3" if any one could show me how to doit with zmv that would be great

Comment: Is there an actual space between the digits and the filename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An script like this might work:

```
for f in *; do
    mv "$f" "${f:3}"
done
```

This will strip the first 3 characters of the filename (the two numbers and the space).

Or something like this:

```
for f in *; do
    mv "$f" "$(printf "$f" | cut -d' ' -f2-)"
done
```

If there is an actual blank space between the number and the rest of the name. This will print everything from the blank space up to the end of the file.

Note that this will only work for a fixed number of digits (first example) or if there's an actual space between the two *fields* (second example), if the case doesn't apply for any of the mentioned solutions, you can still count on regex matching:

```
for f in *; do
    mv "$f" "$(printf "$f" | sed s/[[:digit:]]*\ *//)"
done
```

This would work for any number of leading digits and/or spaces. For example:

```
echo '0001     hellow  aasa 1212.mp3' | sed s/[[:digit:]]*\ *//
```

Will print

```
hellow  aasa 1212.mp3
```

Answer (score 1):

zmv looks complicated to me. I use [pyRenamer](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/01/pyrenamer-easy-mass-file-renaming-in.html) instead. Pretty straightforward even for beginners.